# Greatly reduced wifi speed on Ubuntu 18 with multiple network cards

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

I have a 500mbps connection which I receive in full on both my Macbook and my Android phone, but I can only get 40mbps on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop.

I have tried both my built-in network card (a realtek RTL8192CE) and an external TP-LINK TL-WN722N, but both are getting approximately the same speed.

My kernel version is 4.15.0-50-generic.

So far, I have tried the following:
 * disabling ipv6
 * turning off device power management
 * installing some updated drivers from [here](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce)
 * attempted installing tplink drivers but they didn't seem to be compatible with my kernel version
 * turning off PCIe Activate State Power Management

Any advice would be muchly appreciated!

Some other relevant diagnostics:

lshw output:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: someserialnumber
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=4.15.0-50-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a3200000-a3203fff
  *-network
```

lspci output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf; grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8192ce/parameters/*`

Answer (score 0):

The [user manual for the RTL8192E](https://fccid.io/TX2-RTL8192CE/User-Manual/User-Manual-1291410) shows it is 2.4GHz only.
Likewise, the [TP-Link TL-WL722N](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/tl-wn722n/#specifications) is 2.4GHz only.

Any 500Mbps connection will be using [5GHz frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels), but neither of your WiFi adapters are 5GHz-capable.

If you leapfrog over WiFi and use an Ethernet cable for the desktop, you will get faster connections than 5GHz can provide; you can get [flat cable](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=34648) in various lengths which you can carpet-tape to the baseboard or run under carpet, if you want the cable to be unobtrusive. Otherwise, get a 5GHz capable WiFi adapter.